# Contact form 7 custom options value

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using select shortcode in CF7 to create a dropdown list. The problem is that my values in the `<option>` tag are the same as the names of the option e.g.

```
<select id="#selection">
    <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

I'd like to have my own options. Now I tried with [pipes](http://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/), but that doesn't change the value visibly in the DOM. I need to have the different values visible so that I can manipulate them with jQuery.

Any workaround?

Comment: That *should* change the value in the DOM. Can you show what you've done with the pipes?

Comment: I just put `  [select menu-1 id:select_box "Option 1|opt1" "Option 2|opt2" "Option 3|opt3"]`, and that's it. But when I looked in the DOM, there were still Option 1 etc. in the `value` place. I've sorted it now, in a different way, but still.

Comment: @dingo_d How did you sort this? I would love to have similar functionality.

Comment: I don't think I have solved this issue. I ended up making a workaround in php and jquery that targeted specific options, since I did this for a client.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter("wpcf7_form_tag", function($scanned_tag, $replace){


    if ("selection" === $scanned_tag["name"]) {

        $contact_form = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();

        $number_of_posts = $contact_form->shortcode_attr("number_of_posts");
        $post_type = $contact_form->shortcode_attr("post_type");


        // using $number_of_posts and $post_type here


        $scanned_tag['raw_values'] = [
            //"number_of_posts \"$number_of_posts\" - post_type \"$post_type\" | Option",
              "op1 | Option 1",
            "op2|Option 2",
            "op3|Option 3",
        ];



        $pipes = new WPCF7_Pipes($scanned_tag['raw_values']);

        $scanned_tag['values'] = $pipes->collect_befores();
        $scanned_tag['pipes'] = $pipes;

    }


    return $scanned_tag;

}, 10, 2);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.